# How to add test result attachments during Azure Devops build or release via a C# application?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm wanting to add some test case attachments during a build or release but I'm struggling to find a valid approach to do this. I'm not using MSTest.

I tried creating a custom build/release task but I've found the `azure-devops-node-api` package to be flaky at best, and seemingly lacking contributors.

This is what I would hope to do...

- Use C# if possible
- Have the code/task available for either a build or release across multiple repositories and projects (same organization) without code duplication
- Automatically authenticate with the currently running build/release without needing PAT tokens or any other form of authentication
- Access to both Azure File Storage and Azure Devops
- Works with any build or release agent

Is this achievable? I've seen odd articles in various places but nothing like whats described above. For example [this](https://github.com/ManojBableshwar/VstsTestRestApiSamples/blob/master/PublishResultsFromCsvWithAttachments/PublishResultsFromCsvWithAttachments.cs) shows promise in terms of validating the current build/release in a C# application however it is 4 years old now and doesn't explain how to integrate with a pipeline.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've always leveraged mstest, so within the runner we've had access in c# to the [TestContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.addresultfile?view=mstest-net-1.2.0#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_TestContext_AddResultFile_System_String_) that supports adding the attachements directly to the test result.

It looks like the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) is exposed for adding attachments to the runs though, so I would think you can create something either in c# or in powershell that accomplishes what you are asking.  You will likely need to make sure the agent phase has access to the OAuth token.

> `POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments?api-version=5.1-preview.1`

Comment: Thanks. Sadly I can’t switch to MSTest. I’ll look into the api again although I wanted to avoid authentication details either hardcoded into any code/script or added as variables against the pipeline

Comment: There are quite a few examples I think online of getting the OAuth token for authentication.  It's like a pipeline variable you can reference in the script, you just have to make sure you enable access to it either in the YAML or on the agent phase if you are using the classic pipeline designer.